# Variable undefined in stores: [] and views: [] - Ext-JS 4.1.1a

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm creating my own "library" because I want to keep my code DRY. The idea is just to extend SimpleController and send it a name so it could generically load stores and views which are already created but in my console I'm getting a message that the nameOfController is undefined.

1.) In this example, why is nameOfController undefined?

2.) I know how to extend SimpleController but when is the right time to initialize **nameOfController**? In the `init()` function? Is there some function wich is executed even before loading stores: [] and views: []?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SimpleController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    nameOfController: "",


    stores: ['MyApp.store.' + this.nameOfController],
    views: ['MyApp.view.' + this.nameOfController + '.Index']
```

EDIT: (example of extending)

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'MyApp.controller.SimpleController',

    nameOfController: "Users"  //I want to this nameOfController
                               //changes the one in superclass
});
```

Comment: The expression `this.nameOfController` evaluates immediately, but the "nameOfController" property is only created *after* that entire object literal is evaluated, and the corresponding object is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define constructor for controller. Example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SimpleController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    nameOfController: "",

    //stores: ['MyApp.store.' + this.nameOfController],
    //views: ['MyApp.view.' + this.nameOfController + '.Index']

    constructor: function(config) {
        var name = config.nameOfController;

        config.stores = config.stores || [];
        config.views = config.views || [];

        config.stores.push('MyApp.store.' + name);
        config.views.push('MyApp.view.' + name + '.Index');

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of defining the object, the object is not `this`.

You could use an anonymous self-calling function:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.SimpleController",(function(name) {
  return {
    extend: 'Exp.app.Controller',
    nameOfController: name,
    stores: ['MyApp.store.'+name],
    views: ['MyApp.view.'+name+'.Index']
  };
})("Users"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I think that the Lolo's solution is cleaner. If his solution is not working, I'll try yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
var name = "Users";

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SimpleController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    nameOfController: name,    

    stores: ['MyApp.store.' + name],
    views: ['MyApp.view.' + name + '.Index']
});
```

So, the string is stored in an outer variable.

Comment: Thank you for response. How can I send the variable nameOfController to the superclass? With the this.callParent()? I've edited my question so I'll appreciate if you look it.

Comment: @DavorLozic I don't understand your pattern. Why do you want to set the name of `SimpleController` from within `Users`?

Comment: Because in my SimpleController will be all the logic which I want to share in all my controllers but the only difference is the "name". Let's say, **Users**, **Countries**, **Workers**... They all have CRUD to the database and the logic is same everywhere.

Comment: Look at the Lolo's solution. I think that's it. :)